# How to bind multicolumn radcombo box values to Text boxes client side?

Tags: javascript, telerik, rad-controls, radcombobox

i am using multicolumn rad combo box, in that i have 5 columns like code,name,description, date,remarks. I have to bind these 3 columns values to 3 text boxes when combo box selection changed except value field and text field of combobox. Any body know please share an example.

my aspx page code for combo box is

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbTendernoticeno" runat="server" MarkFirstMatch="true" 
                                                        AllowCustomText="false" TabIndex="2" DropDownWidth="230px" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
                                                        EmptyMessage="--Select--" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"
                                                         onselectedindexchanged="cmbTendernoticeno_SelectedIndexChanged">


    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="width: 200px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    Tendor No.
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    Tendor date
                </td>
               <td style="width: 100px;">
                    Code
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    Code
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    Code
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="width: 200px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NOTICE_NO")%>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NOTICE_DATE", "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")%>
                </td>
                 <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ACCEPT_DATE")%>
                </td>
                 <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TENDER_OPEN_DATE")%>
                </td>
                 <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OPENING_PLACE")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            Tender Date</label><sup>*</sup>
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtTenderDate" runat="server" TabIndex="3" Enabled="false">
        </telerik:RadTextBox>

    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>
            Last Date for reciept of Tender</label><sup>*</sup>
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtLastdtforrcptTender" runat="server" TabIndex="4" Enabled="false">
        </telerik:RadTextBox >

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            Date of Opening</label><sup>*</sup>
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadTextBox  ID="txtDateofOpening" TabIndex="5" runat="server" Enabled="false">
        </telerik:RadTextBox >

    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>
            Place of Opening</label><sup>*</sup>
    </td>
    <td>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPlaceofopening" MaxLength="500" runat="server" TabIndex="6" Enabled="false">
            <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="validateAlphanumeric" />
        </telerik:RadTextBox>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

cs file code is

```
    public void fillTendernoticeno()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = ObjpsBal.fillTendernoticeno();
            cmbTendernoticeno.DataTextField = "NOTICE_NO";
            cmbTendernoticeno.DataValueField="NOTICE_DATE";
            cmbTendernoticeno.DataSource=ds;
            cmbTendernoticeno.DataBind();
        }
```

now i want to get the combo box multicolumn values(NOTICE_DATE,ACCEPT_DATE,TENDER_OPEN_DATE,OPENING_PLACE) and has to show in proper text boxes.

Comment: Could you post some code please?  Tough to tell exactly what you are asking from the description provided.

Comment: hi Ryan O'neil find i updated my question